# Changing totem subtitle downloder folder

Tags: default, totem, subtitle

Totem subtitle downloader plugin is awesome.

Is there any way in which i can change default folder `~/.cache/totem/subtitles` to desired one?

I want to subtitles to be saved. subtitle saved in `~/.cache/totem/subtitles` is deleted when closing totem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Totem/plugin does not provide such an option in Preferences, etc. you can do this by creating a custom folder anywhere you like (e.g. `mkdir ~/Videos/Subtitles`) and then, having Totem closed, you can create a symbolic link like this:

```
rmdir ~/.cache/totem/subtitles
ln -s ~/Videos/Subtitles ~/.cache/totem/subtitles
```

Comment: tried 'rm ~/.cache/totem/subtitles', resulted in 'rm: cannot remove ‘/home/shravan/.cache/totem/subtitles’: Is a directory'

Comment: Sorry for typo, the command shoul be rmdir